# How to find a particular requirement in a file written in columms and copy it to another file

Tags: python

I have a file written in columns like this (I write the first rows but is longer):

```
Ncol 10  Nrow 9276
   NO_POL   =            2
   NO_IF    =            8
NO.   ANTENNA   SUBARRAY   TSYS   TANT
 1       1         1        37     35 
 2                          37     35
 3                          37     35
 4       1         1        37     35
 5                          37     35
 6                          37     35
 7       3         1        37     35
 8                          37     35
 9                          37     35
10       3         1        37     35
11                          37     35
```

I want to copy in another file which number of antennas appear in this file but I want that the number of the antenna appear only once in the other file. The maximum number of antennas is 10.

What I have done is read the file in columns starting in the 5 row. Like I only want to see in the lines where the number of the antenna appears I have put the condition of that the length of the columns have to be more than 3. This is the code I have written to do this, but nothing is written in my new_file:

```
with open('file') as f1:
    with open('new_file','a') as f2:
        for i in range(1,11): 
            for line in f1.readlines()[4:]:
                columns = line.split()
                if len(columns) > 3 and columns[1] == i:
                    f2.write(i+'\n')
                    break
```

I think the problem could be in the condition of the number of antenna matching with i, but I don't know why... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alternative route... `tail +5 file.dat | cut -c4,10 | sort | uniq > new_file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to fix.  I'll start by just correcting the type/code errors, and then address the algorithm itself.

### Code issues

For starters, every time you call f1.readlines(), it reads from where it left off reading.  So you only get the rest of the file instead of the entire file after the first read.  What you'll have to do is store the contents of the file in a list outside of the loop, and then you'll loop in the same way you currently do except with line coming from this list instead of the file.

Next, you're trying to compare a string with an integer in your columns[1]==i, you have to comvert one into the other, so maybe int(columns[1])==i in the comparison.

A similar error occurs when you try to write to the output file, you have to convert i into a string in order to add '\n' to it, so something like f2.write(str(i)+'\n') would do it.

The resulting code with these changes would be:

```
f1=open('file')
contents=f1.readlines()[4:]
f1.close() #we don't need it anymore
with open('new_file','a') as f2:
    for i in range(1,11):
        for line in contents:
            columns = line.split()
            if len(columns) > 3 and int(columns[1]) == i:
                f2.write(str(i)+'\n')
                break
```

It seems to work as you want on my machine.

### Algorithm

What you are doing is picking an antenna number, and then looking through the entire file to see if there is a line with that antenna number present.  This is certainly one approach, but if you intend to do this sort of processing for large files this algorithm will take quite some time.  An alternative, more efficient approach is to use a set.

Python has a set() function which creates an empty set, and then you add elements to the set with the add() function.

So you might end up doing something like this:

```
antennae=set()
f1=open('file')
lineno=1
for line in f1:
    if lineno >= 5:
        row = line.split()
        if len(row) > 3:
            antennae.add(int(row[1]))
    lineno+=1
f1.close()
f2=open('new_file','a')
for antenna in antennae:
    f2.write(str(antenna)+'\n')
f2.close()
```

This version is efficient both in memory and in time, since we're only reading lines as we need them (and we're using python's efficient reading algorithms) while also only checking each line once instead of once per antenna value.

Comment: This looks good, but I think you want to loop through `for antenna in set(antennae):` instead to print out unique values...

Comment: But antennae is already a set, do I need to tell it antennae is a set again in the loop?  It seems to work when I tested it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed the declaration at the top. I am used to using `set()` to generate a set from a list. Good explanations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I get what I wanted now :) Only one point, I thought that if you use `with open('file') as f:` you don't need to close the file. But I'm a beginner here, so I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah good catch, I always just closed the file out of habit but the with statement does that automatically.  I'll remove it from the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for i in range(1,11): 
        for line in f1.readlines()[4:]:
```

What this does is "Try to read all the lines in the file 10 times over". That does not sound correct...

```
            if len(columns) > 3 and columns[1] == i:
```

So `i`is the row count (it doesn't work because of the first problem, but let's assume it does) and you use it to select a column? that does not sound right either.

Maybe something like this (not tested):

```
f1 = open('file');
f2 = open('new_file', 'a');
for line in f1.readlines()[4:]:
    columns = line.split()
    if len(columns) > 3:
        f2.write(columns[0]+'\n')
```

In the future I suggest adding debug printing in your code, that usually helps.

Comment: This works to identify while lines have antenna values, but doesn't seem to work for the OP request to have one entry per antenna in the destination file. You could either build a list of already written values and only write if the value is not in that list, or generate a set of values and write out the `set()` afterwards in a separate loop.